# Closed form expression for singular values of a "two vector" matrix

Tags: matrices, svd

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times 2}$ such that it has full column rank, i.e, $a_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{d} $ and $a_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{d} $ are linearly independent where $A=\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2\end{bmatrix}$. Since $A$ is of rank $2$, I am wondering if there are any closed form expressions for the two singular values of $A$ in terms of $a_1$ and $a_2$.

My attempt: The largest singular value can be characterized by 
$$
\sigma_1(A)^2=\sup_{\|x\|_2=1} \|A x\|_2^2,
$$
and hence can be written as
\begin{align*}
\sigma_1(A)^2  &= \sup_{\theta} \| a_1 \cdot \cos(\theta) + a_2 \cdot \sin(\theta) \|_2^2,\\
&=\sup_{\theta} \| a_1 \|^2 \cdot \cos^2\theta + \|a_2\|^2 \cdot \sin^2 \theta \ + 2 \langle a_1, a_2 \rangle \sin \theta \cos \theta \\
&=\frac{\|a_1\|^2+\|a_2\|^2}{2} + \sup_\theta \left[ \cos 2\theta \left(\frac{\|a_1\|^2 -\|a_2\|^2}{2} \right)  + \sin 2\theta \cdot \langle a_1, a_2 \rangle \right] \\
&=\frac{\|a_1\|^2+\|a_2\|^2}{2}  + \sqrt{  \left(\frac{\|a_1\|^2 -\|a_2\|^2}{2} \right)^2 +  \langle a_1, a_2 \rangle^2 }.
\end{align*}
Can a similar derivation be done for $\sigma_2(A)^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a matrix of column vectors
$$
 \mathbf{A} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  v_{1} & v_{2}
\end{array} \right]
\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times 2}.
$$
Form the product matrix
$$
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} &= 
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  v_{1}\bar{v}_{1} & v_{1}\bar{v}_{2} \\
  v_{2}\bar{v}_{1} & v_{2}\bar{v}_{2} \\
\end{array} \right]
\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2} \\[3pt]
%
&= 
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 m & v_{1}\bar{v}_{2} \\
  v_{2}\bar{v}_{1} & m \\
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$
The eigenvalues of this matrix are
$$
 \lambda \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right) =
%
\frac{1}{2} \left(
m \pm
\lvert v_{1}v_{2}^{*} \rvert
\right)
$$
The singular values are
$$
 \sigma_{\pm} = \sqrt{\lambda\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right)} 
 = \sqrt{
\frac{1}{2} \left(
m \pm
\lvert v_{1}v_{2}^{*} \rvert
\right)
}
$$

Comment: How is $v_1 \bar{v}_1 = v_2 \bar{v}_2 = m$ ?